# Dynamic set language string source

Tags: android, xml, lang

Is it possible in Android dynamic set language string source?

Example: I have in app 2 language resources, now I need force one layout file and here I want use for example English resources but system and UI etc must stay in default language. I want only set language resources for one xml file not for whole system. Is this possible? Or any idea. Thx

Comment: Herez my detail answer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720987/how-to-update-the-language-of-application-by-user-selected-one/31721568#31721568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to change the language Dynamically:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

You can get the list of country code from [here](https://developers.google.com/igoogle/docs/i18n?csw=1).

Comment: yes this working but after restart app I have changed UI language. But thx.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Resources res = context.getResources(); // Change locale settings in the app.
 DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
 android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
 conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
 res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```