# How to change the application language by user choice?

Tags: android, lang

In my project there is a option for the user to select language. The whole application should change by selecting the language. Language is fetched from the server side.

I referred various sites and links, but couldn't find a better solution. Localization is not possible, because it's a huge app and also language is not fixed , it is fetched from the server side and it can be varied.

Is any other solution is available? Please help...

Comment: After setting the locale, update the configuration.

Comment: Android has a string localization. Depending on which language is selected on your device, such language and content is displayed in your application. Strings must be in different xml files.Or you should definitely get the translation from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its not recommended to use separate language for your  app other than the Android system's  . But you can still change it .

Below is the code :

```
private void setLocale (String localeCode , Bundle b ){
    Log.d(TAG+"set location function: "+localeCode);
    locale = new Locale(localeCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    UserDetail.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);
}
```

Use this method call on some user trigger:

```
setLocale("en-us",savedInstanceStat); // for english
setLocale("ar",savedInstanceStat); // for arabic
```

To learn more about android locals:
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

This will set the locale of the app to the desired one, not changing the global locale set on the device. All of the native localisation mechanisms will work with the context locale.